Why is the text field from the real-time index blank when querying in manticoresearch?
There is the following config of manticoresearch:
searchd {
    listen = 9312
    listen = 9306:mysql
    listen = 9308:http
    log = /var/log/manticore/searchd.log
    query_log = /var/log/manticore/query.log
    pid_file = /var/run/manticore/searchd.pid
    #data_dir = /var/lib/manticore
}

source messages_sql {
        type = mysql
        sql_host = wahelp.mysql
        sql_user = wahelp
        sql_pass = secret
        sql_db = wahelp
        sql_query =  SELECT id, message,  message_type + 0 message_type, status + 0 status,  unix_timestamp(created_at) created_at from messages
        sql_field_string = message
        sql_attr_uint = message_type
        sql_attr_uint = status
        sql_attr_timestamp = created_at
}

table messages_plain {
  type   = plain
  source = messages_sql
  path   = /var/lib/manticore/messages_plain
}

table messages_rt {
    type = rt
    path = /var/lib/manticore/messages_rt
    rt_field = message
    rt_attr_uint = message_type
    rt_attr_uint = status
    rt_attr_timestamp = created_at
}

table messages
{
    type = distributed
    local = messages_plain
    local = messages_rt
}

When querying the messages table, if rows from both messages_plain and messages_rt indexes are included, then the message field for messages_rt is empty. But if the result contains only row from messages_rt, then the message field is not empty.
What could be the reason? Which direction should I look in?
What could be the reason? Which direction should I look in?

Fields, by thesemvesl are not 'stored' so can't be retrieved. (when they are indexed, they are tokenized and injected into the 'inverted index' - but can't get back the original text that way)
On the 'plain' index, you used sql_field_string to make messages BOTH an field AND an attribute - as an attribute, it CAN be retrieved.
In the RT index its only a Field.
Not sure, but think you can do
rt_field = message
rt_attr_string = message

to make BOTH a field and string attribute with the same name.
